# yii script publish and register

Tags: javascript, yii

I have a ajax call where I return the output of renderFile as a Json Object.  Within the rendered file I publish and register a script file.  However, when the rendered html is appended to the body element the script is not loaded.  Other statically listed scripts are loaded.
Any clues?

Comment: More information would be nice. Show us some HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered scripts will be included when you call render(), or when you call renderPartial() with processOutput parameter=true.